# fetch and 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: fetch-api

here is my javascript:

```
fetch(
"https://api-gateway.leroymerlin.fr/api-product/v2/products/_search",
{
    mode: 'no-cors', // It can be no-cors, cors, same-origin
    method: 'GET', // The method
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
    "X-Gateway-APIKey": "..mykeySecret..."
    },
    params: {
        'q': 'marteau',
    },
}
```

).then( response => {console.log(response)}).catch((error) => console.log(error));

I have this error:
GET https://api-gateway.leroymerlin.fr/api-product/v2/products/_search 401 (Unauthorized)

I'm sur that the secretKey is valid, what is the problem ?

Thanks all !

Comment: it work very good in postman...

Comment: The issue is that you used `no-cors`. I wrote about what `no-cors` is in detail here: https://evertpot.com/no-cors/ . When you use no-cors, certain headers are automatically removed, and there's other restrictions.

Comment: Hey, is I remove no-cors, I have this message: Access to fetch at 'https://api-gateway.leroymerlin.fr/api-product/v2/products/_search' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: So the server you are trying to use has disabled accessing their API via a browser. Only the API owner can change this. Try using the API with a server-side language.